# HTML Email Signature not rendering in Outlook 2016 any idea why?

Tags: html, css, email, outlook

Within this signature I think there are some problems with the HTML tagging as it does not render in Microsoft Outlook 2016. Does anyone know a solution to this or have any pointers on how to format an Outlook Email Signature?

Thanks.

```
<div style="max-width:470px;"> <table> <tbody> <tr valign="top"> <td style="font:14px Arial; color:#646464; padding-left:10px"> <div> <b>Howard Chalk</b> <br> <span>Business Development Manager, iDealFILE</span> </div> <div style="color:#000;font-size:13px; padding:5px 0"> <a href="http://idealfile.co.uk/general-data-protection-regulation-set-to-change-the-motor-sales-industry/?utm_medium=email&utm_source=signature (http://idealfile.co.uk/general-data-protection-regulation-set-to-change-the-motor-sales-industry/?utm_medium&#x3D;email&amp;utm_source&%23x3D;signature) "> Are you ready for GDPR? </a> </div> <div style="color:#8d8d8d; font-size:13px; padding:5px 0"> <span style="white-space:nowrap"> <span style="color:#45668E"> p: </span> <a style="color:#8d8d8d;text-decoration:none" href="tel:01635 283616" target="_blank"> 01635 283616 </a> | <span style="color:#45668E">m:</span> <a style="color:#8d8d8d;text-decoration:none" href="tel:07786 081359" target="_blank"> 07786 081359 </a> | </span> <span style="white-space:nowrap"> <span style="color:#45668E"> e: </span> <a style="color:#8d8d8d;text-decoration:none" href="mailto:howard.chalk@motordocs.co.uk" target="_blank"> howard.chalk@motordocs.co.uk </a> | </span> <span style="white-space:nowrap"> <span style="color:#45668E"> w: </span> <a style="color:#8d8d8d;text-decoration:none" href="http://www.idealfile.co.uk/?utm_medium=email&utm_source=signature (http://www.idealfile.co.uk/?utm_medium&#x3D;email&amp;utm_source&%23x3D;signature) " target="_blank"> www.idealfile.co.uk </a> </span> </div> <div style="margin-top:5px"> <a href="https://www.linkedin.com/in/howard-chalk-0a9b0826/" style="text-decoration:none;" target="_blank"> <img alt="LinkedIn" style="width:16px; height:16px;" src="https://s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/canddi.email/icons/linkedin-icon.png"> </a> <a href="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Chxfjye49fM&t=12s (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v&#x3D;Chxfjye49fM&amp;t&%23x3D;12s) " style="text-decoration:none;" target="_blank"> <img alt="Youtube" style="width:16px; height:16px;" src="https://s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/canddi.email/icons/youtube-icon.png"> </a> <p> <a href="https://www.canddi.com/?utm_medium=email&utm_source=poweredby" style="font-size: 11px; color:#F7931E;"> <i>Powered by CANDDi.</i> </a> </p> </div> </td> </tr> </tbody> </table> </div>
```

Comment: can you share me the screenshot of the email template

Comment: Have you tried opening as a web page to see if the formatting is still an issue? Also, have you checked the formatting is correct? using something like: https://validator.w3.org/

Answer (score 0):

For outlook, just copy/paste the rendered html in the signature editor.

go to [this link](http://htmledit.squarefree.com/) and render the HTML code, then copy/paste it